# How to find search criteria2 if criteria1 not displayed in Excel by using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook1-->Sheet3 having inputs (I am providing 24 `monthday`s: 110, 125, 210,.......1210, 1225) for Marco. Input will be always `monthday`s regardless of years, on 10th and 25th of every month will receive data. If mentioned days are not non-business day, suppose if 10th is holiday it could be replaced by something between 11th and 15th. Same way if 25th is holiday there is possibility 26th to 30th of every month. Based on above conditions in sheet1 needs to filter the data. E.g.: if `monthday` is 110, I will search in sheet1. Suppose sheet1 doesn't have data for mentioned "110" there is possibility till "115"(But Ideally I am providing only 24th days in my input "sheet3"). Please guide/help me regarding issue make vba.

```
Sub Creation()

Workbooks("Data").Sheets("Sheet3").Activate

For X = 1 To 24

Workbooks("Data").Sheets("Sheet3").Activate

If Range("A" & X).Value > 0 Then


monthday = Range("A" & X).Value

'MsgBox ("Creating Inventory Options for following: " & Range("A" & X))
If monthday > 0 Then
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
        With NewBook
            .Title = monthday
            Test1Str = "Seperate_ Data Option Allocation_"
            TestStr = monthday

            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\Macro Practice\" & Test1Str & TestStr
            Workbooks("Seperate_ Data Option Allocation_" & TestStr).Save

             Workbooks("Seperate_ Data Option Allocation_" & TestStr).Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Data1"

    Workbooks("Seperate_ Data Option Allocation_" & TestStr).Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Data2"
    Workbooks("Seperate_ Data Option Allocation_" & TestStr).Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "Calculation"
    Workbooks("Seperate_ Data Option Allocation_" & TestStr).Sheets.Add.Name = "Validation"           
    Workbooks("Data").Activate     
    Workbooks("Data").Sheets("Data2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:=Teststr
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks("Seperate_ Data Option Allocation_" & TestStr).Sheets("Data2").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Workbooks("Seperate_ Data Option Allocation_" & TestStr).Save
    end with
end if
next x
end sub
```

Comment: If you come with specific problem in your code then we can help you .. Please try to make a code

Comment: Hi Sathish, In Criteria1:=Teststr how to apply the conditions and where I need to provide non business day information?

Answer (score 0):

I think above code copy all the data from Data work book .. better replace the below two lines

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
```

with

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
   rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Comment: Please let me know if one condition is not displayed in filter I need to search another condition as per above mentioned conditions. Please provide good idea.